# UIcollectionView sizing issue

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

My all output string on console.

```
15:57:56.116319+0500 Flo[5489:191774] The behavior of the UICollectionViewFlowLayout is not defined because:
2020-02-14 15:57:56.116509+0500 Flo[5489:191774] the item width must be less than the width of the UICollectionView minus the section insets left and right values, minus the content insets left and right values.
2020-02-14 15:57:56.116638+0500 Flo[5489:191774] Please check the values returned by the delegate.
2020-02-14 15:57:56.116911+0500 Flo[5489:191774] The relevant UICollectionViewFlowLayout instance is <UICollectionViewFlowLayout: 0x7fc39cd05c80>, and it is attached to <UICollectionView: 0x7fc39d80ca00; frame = (0 44; 414 589); clipsToBounds = YES; autoresize = H; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x600002e75f50>; layer = <CALayer: 0x60000203d0e0>; contentOffset: {-15, -15}; contentSize: {384, 760}; adjustedContentInset: {15, 15, 10, 15}; layout: <UICollectionViewFlowLayout: 0x7fc39cd05c80>; dataSource: <Flo.DashboardViewController: 0x7fc39ce07930>>.
2020-02-14 15:57:56.117059+0500 Flo[5489:191774] Make a symbolic breakpoint at UICollectionViewFlowLayoutBreakForInvalidSizes to catch this in the debugger.
2020-02-14 15:57:56.117211+0500 Flo[5489:191774] The behavior of the UICollectionViewFlowLayout is not defined because:
2020-02-14 15:57:56.117328+0500 Flo[5489:191774] the item width must be less than the width of the UICollectionView minus the section insets left and right values, minus the content insets left and right values.
2020-02-14 15:57:56.129857+0500 Flo[5489:191774] Please check the values returned by the delegate.
2020-02-14 15:57:56.130183+0500 Flo[5489:191774] The relevant UICollectionViewFlowLayout instance is <UICollectionViewFlowLayout: 0x7fc39cd05c80>, and it is attached to <UICollectionView: 0x7fc39d80ca00; frame = (0 44; 414 589); clipsToBounds = YES; autoresize = H; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x600002e75f50>; layer = <CALayer: 0x60000203d0e0>; contentOffset: {-15, -15}; contentSize: {384, 760}; adjustedContentInset: {15, 15, 10, 15}; layout: <UICollectionViewFlowLayout: 0x7fc39cd05c80>; dataSource: <Flo.DashboardViewController: 0x7fc39ce07930>>.
2020-02-14 15:57:56.130318+0500 Flo[5489:191774] Make a symbolic breakpoint at UICollectionViewFlowLayoutBreakForInvalidSizes to catch this in the debugger.
2020-02-14 15:57:56.130450+0500 Flo[5489:191774] The behavior of the UICollectionViewFlowLayout is not defined because:
2020-02-14 15:57:56.130591+0500 Flo[5489:191774] the item width must be less than the width of the UICollectionView minus the section insets left and right values, minus the content insets left and right values.
2020-02-14 15:57:56.130702+0500 Flo[5489:191774] Please check the values returned by the delegate.
2020-02-14 15:57:56.130939+0500 Flo[5489:191774] The relevant UICollectionViewFlowLayout instance is <UICollectionViewFlowLayout: 0x7fc39cd05c80>, and it is attached to <UICollectionView: 0x7fc39d80ca00; frame = (0 44; 414 589); clipsToBounds = YES; autoresize = H; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x600002e75f50>; layer = <CALayer: 0x60000203d0e0>; contentOffset: {-15, -15}; contentSize: {384, 760}; adjustedContentInset: {15, 15, 10, 15}; layout: <UICollectionViewFlowLayout: 0x7fc39cd05c80>; dataSource: <Flo.DashboardViewController: 0x7fc39ce07930>>.
2020-02-14 15:57:56.131069+0500 Flo[5489:191774] Make a symbolic breakpoint at UICollectionViewFlowLayoutBreakForInvalidSizes to catch this in the debugger.
2020-02-14 15:57:56.131166+0500 Flo[5489:191774] The behavior of the UICollectionViewFlowLayout is not defined because:
2020-02-14 15:57:56.131269+0500 Flo[5489:191774] the item width must be less than the width of the UICollectionView minus the section insets left and right values, minus the content insets left and right values.
2020-02-14 15:57:56.131613+0500 Flo[5489:191774] Please check the values returned by the delegate.
2020-02-14 15:57:56.132090+0500 Flo[5489:191774] The relevant UICollectionViewFlowLayout instance is <UICollectionViewFlowLayout: 0x7fc39cd05c80>, and it is attached to <UICollectionView: 0x7fc39d80ca00; frame = (0 44; 414 589); clipsToBounds = YES; autoresize = H; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x600002e75f50>; layer = <CALayer: 0x60000203d0e0>; contentOffset: {-15, -15}; contentSize: {384, 760}; adjustedContentInset: {15, 15, 10, 15}; layout: <UICollectionViewFlowLayout: 0x7fc39cd05c80>; dataSource: <Flo.DashboardViewController: 0x7fc39ce07930>>.
2020-02-14 15:57:56.132379+0500 Flo[5489:191774] Make a symbolic breakpoint at UICollectionViewFlowLayoutBreakForInvalidSizes to catch this in the debugger.
2020-02-14 15:57:56.132827+0500 Flo[5489:191774] The behavior of the UICollectionViewFlowLayout is not defined because:
2020-02-14 15:57:56.133225+0500 Flo[5489:191774] the item width must be less than the width of the UICollectionView minus the section insets left and right values, minus the content insets left and right values.
2020-02-14 15:57:56.133876+0500 Flo[5489:191774] Please check the values returned by the delegate.
2020-02-14 15:57:56.134260+0500 Flo[5489:191774] The relevant UICollectionViewFlowLayout instance is <UICollectionViewFlowLayout: 0x7fc39cd05c80>, and it is attached to <UICollectionView: 0x7fc39d80ca00; frame = (0 44; 414 589); clipsToBounds = YES; autoresize = H; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x600002e75f50>; layer = <CALayer: 0x60000203d0e0>; contentOffset: {-15, -15}; contentSize: {384, 760}; adjustedContentInset: {15, 15, 10, 15}; layout: <UICollectionViewFlowLayout: 0x7fc39cd05c80>; dataSource: <Flo.DashboardViewController: 0x7fc39ce07930>>.
2020-02-14 15:57:56.134523+0500 Flo[5489:191774] Make a symbolic breakpoint at UICollectionViewFlowLayoutBreakForInvalidSizes to catch this in the debugger.
2020-02-14 15:57:56.134832+0500 Flo[5489:191774] The behavior of the UICollectionViewFlowLayout is not defined because:
2020-02-14 15:57:56.135166+0500 Flo[5489:191774] the item width must be less than the width of the UICollectionView minus the section insets left and right values, minus the content insets left and right values.
2020-02-14 15:57:56.135464+0500 Flo[5489:191774] Please check the values returned by the delegate.
2020-02-14 15:57:56.135893+0500 Flo[5489:191774] The relevant UICollectionViewFlowLayout instance is <UICollectionViewFlowLayout: 0x7fc39cd05c80>, and it is attached to <UICollectionView: 0x7fc39d80ca00; frame = (0 44; 414 589); clipsToBounds = YES; autoresize = H; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x600002e75f50>; layer = <CALayer: 0x60000203d0e0>; contentOffset: {-15, -15}; contentSize: {384, 760}; adjustedContentInset: {15, 15, 10, 15}; layout: <UICollectionViewFlowLayout: 0x7fc39cd05c80>; dataSource: <Flo.DashboardViewController: 0x7fc39ce07930>>.
2020-02-14 15:57:56.136121+0500 Flo[5489:191774] Make a symbolic breakpoint at UICollectionViewFlowLayoutBreakForInvalidSizes to catch this in the debugger.
2020-02-14 15:57:56.136446+0500 Flo[5489:191774] The behavior of the UICollectionViewFlowLayout is not defined because:
2020-02-14 15:57:56.136759+0500 Flo[5489:191774] the item width must be less than the width of the UICollectionView minus the section insets left and right values, minus the content insets left and right values.
2020-02-14 15:57:56.137100+0500 Flo[5489:191774] Please check the values returned by the delegate.
2020-02-14 15:57:56.137436+0500 Flo[5489:191774] The relevant UICollectionViewFlowLayout instance is <UICollectionViewFlowLayout: 0x7fc39cd05c80>, and it is attached to <UICollectionView: 0x7fc39d80ca00; frame = (0 44; 414 589); clipsToBounds = YES; autoresize = H; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x600002e75f50>; layer = <CALayer: 0x60000203d0e0>; contentOffset: {-15, -15}; contentSize: {384, 760}; adjustedContentInset: {15, 15, 10, 15}; layout: <UICollectionViewFlowLayout: 0x7fc39cd05c80>; dataSource: <Flo.DashboardViewController: 0x7fc39ce07930>>.
2020-02-14 15:57:56.137683+0500 Flo[5489:191774] Make a symbolic breakpoint at UICollectionViewFlowLayoutBreakForInvalidSizes to catch this in the debugger.
```

Comment: If this is the same problem and related to your yesterday question you should just copy this debug log there, _**editing your question**_ to insert these info, so that everything is together.

Comment: is there any issue in your design when you run the code ?

Comment: Please add your code at least collectionflowlayout delegate code. thanks

Comment: func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
        return CGSize(width: collectionView.frame.width * 0.9, height: collectionView.frame.height*0.5)
    }

Comment: the size of the collection view is equal to safe area . and few cells at start goes out of bound and remaining cells stays within the screen

Answer (score 2):

You need to double check these things:

1. Collection view bounds (width, height), where and how do you set them.
2. Collection view cell bounds (width, height). Width and height of cells must not be more than collection view bounds.
3. Check collection view content insets, they can break your layout. If cell size is more, than (Collection view bounds - collectionView insets), than you can have this error.

Comment: few cells at start goes out of bound  like 4 out of 50 shows this behavior and remaining cells stays within the screen

Comment: Try to replace collectionView.frame.width * 0.9 with other value, for example width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width - collectionView.inset.left - collectionView.inset.right.

Comment: UPD. Provide your collection view initialisation code, bounds or constraints.